# Utilizar el copiador de turno instalado en Windows desde C#

Tags: c#, windows

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación escrita en C# en la que en cierto punto se debe de mandar a copiar una carpetas seleccionadas por el usuario hacia otro destino, el problema es que necesito que dicha acción la realice el copiador de turno por defecto de Windows, que podría ser el que trae instalado el sistema en un principio o tal vez otro que haya sido instalado posteriormente y que se encuentre actualmente cumpliendo esta función.

Pregunto entonces si existe en C# la manera de imitar el comportamiento de Windows de cuando se selecciona una carpeta o algún archivo, mandándolo a copiar y luego se presiona pegar en otro sitio, porque esto es lo que creo que desencadena esta acción.

El objetivo no es utilizar las herramientas de `System.IO`  puesto que por esa vía tendría que crear un copiador propio con visual incluido. Para evitar esto estoy intentando buscar la manera de al menos provocar el evento que dispara al copiador de Windows o a otro instalado en el sistema, pero no he tenido suerte, parece que es algo que no es posible con C#.

Ya intenté mediante `Process` pero lo más cercano es la llamada mediante consola por parámetros a "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" pero esto solo permite abrir un directorio o un archivo en este, otra forma fue detectar de forma manual la presencia de copiadores externos como el SuperCopier o el UltraCopier pero en estos casos los mismos no estaban construidos sus .exe en forma de aceptar parámetros porque solo aceptaban una sesión a la vez activa en Windows. Pensé entonces que como existe "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" también debería de existir un ejecutable semejante que disparara el copiador de Windows pero no lo he encontrado.

Entonces creo que solo me queda una alternativa, tal vez imitar el evento ¨CTRL + V¨ de alguna forma hacia algún directorio a modo de que responda el procedimiento por defecto configurado en Windows actualmente.

Comment: Buenas, sí existe tienes que usar `using System.IO;` y ahí tienes dos que te interesan de clases `Directory` y `File`. Como dicen sus nombres son para hacer operaciones de directorio y fichero como mover, copiar, pegar, borrar, etc.

Comment: Para más ayuda necesitaríamos que no pases algún ejemplo de que no te funciona para replicarlo para así buscar alguna alternativa.

Comment: El objetivo no es utilizar las herramientas de   `System.IO` puesto que por esa vía tendría que crear un copiador propio con visual incluido. Para evitar esto estoy intentando buscar la manera de al menos provocar el evento que dispara al copiador de Windows o a otro instalado en el sistema, pero no he tenido suerte, parece que es algo que no es posible con C#

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes hacer en caso de no usar él System.io puedes usar `Process` para ejecutar comandas de cmd lo cuales les puedes pasar parámetros y devolverlos, lo siguiente sería crear un controlador nuevo a mano para eso.

Comment: Edite la pregunta, hay respondo a tu sugerencia

Comment: Creo que toda tu pregunta se resume en pocas palabras y voy a adivinar "quiero que salga la ventanita que sale cuando copio archivos desde el sistema operativo"... es eso?????

Comment: Exacto, es lo que necesito, el copiador de Windows o el que este supliendo esa función en el momento

Comment: Pero si quieres la ventanita es mucho más simple crear una que se parezca que lo quieres hacer tu

Comment: No es así, el problema es que los clientes prefieren las opciones que vienen por defecto con copiadores especializados, tales como el supercopier o el ultracopier, Y el tiempo necesario para imitar sus funciones es largo y costoso, de momento estamos trabajando en el desarrollo de un copiador propio, pero encontrar la respuesta a esta pregunta agilizaría el proyecto.

Comment: El caso del copiador de Windows es la última opción puesto que es demasiado simple y no trae más opciones durante el proceso de copia, pero el punto es que se dispara igual que el resto, al llamar a un desconocido evento de copia a algún sitio.

Comment: Hola @CodeMas podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te resultó útil, gracias

Comment: Si lo fue, en el futuro planteo crear otra pregunta para el resto de las dudas pendientes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar el cuadro de dialogo de Windows en las operaciones con ficheros debe utilizar el **espacio de nombres Microsoft.VisualBasic**. Para ello debe agregar la referencia a su proyecto, por lo que debe ir al **panel Solution Explorer** dar clic derecho sobre **References** y en el menú contextual que se despliega marcar la **opción Add Reference...** :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la ventana que sale deberá desplegar la **opción Assemblies** y seleccionar la **opción  Framework**, posteriormente seleccione la casilla **Microsoft.VisualBasic**, finalmente de clic en el botón Aceptar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente deberá poner en la parte de los **usings**:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

Y el código para copiar un fichero de un lugar a otro sería:

```
FileSystem.CopyFile(@"D:\MiFichero.jpg", @"C:\Prueba\MiFichero.jpg", UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.DoNothing);
```

Usas la **función CopyFile** la cual recibe **4 parámetros**, el primero es de tipo **string** y se refiere a la ubicación original del fichero, el segundo es igualmente de tipo **string** y es la ruta destino hacia donde se copiará el fichero, el tercer y cuarto parámetro son utilizados para incluir o no opciones propias del cuadro de dialogo como pueden ser sobrescribir el archivo, cancelar la operación, etc. Esta función tiene varias sobrecargas, yo utilice la de **4 parámetros**.

Existe además, la **función CopyDirectory** la cual como su nombre indica es utilizada para copiar directorios enteros:

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory(@"D:\Carpeta", @"C:\Prueba", UIOption.AllDialogs, UICancelOption.DoNothing);
```

Analiza este código y adáptalo a tus necesidades.

**Referencia**: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-provide-a-progress-dialog-box-for-file-operations

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, el código funciona bien y logra disparar al copiador de windows , De todas formas la duda sobre como lanzar a el copiador instalado por defecto sigue en el aire, al menos bajo la teoría de imitar el evento  ¨CTRL+V¨ del explorador. De momento pienso crear una nueva pregunta con este objetivo específico. Pero te reitero , gracias, es realmente muy útil tu información.

Comment: la siguiente pregunta es [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577795/disparar-en-evento-ctrlv-en-el-explorador-de-windows)