# Disparar en evento CTRL+V en el explorador de Windows desde C#

Tags: c#, windows

Desde C# existe la manera  de imitar el evento `CTRL+V` en el explorador de window? Me refiero al `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`. Generalmente este evento dispara al copiador de turno  instalado en el sistema, el cual suele ser el copiador de windows.

En una pregunta anterior ya se abordo como llamar programaticamente al copiador por defecto que trae windows  [pregunta en stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/576137/utilizar-el-copiador-de-turno-instalado-en-windows-desde-c/577407#577407)

El objetivo no es utilizar el copiador antes mencionado, sino que con la utilización del evento del teclado obligar a salir al copiador responsable de esta función en este momento

Cabe mencionar que la utilización de `Process` y la búsqueda manual del ejecutable del copiador de turno no suele funcionar puesto que muchos de estos copiadores se alojan en el sistema y solo admiten  una cesión en funcionamiento por vez.

Además la utilización de `System.IO` para la copia de  archivos trae implícito la necesidad de la creación de un visual, lo cual no es el objetivo de esta pregunta.

Comment: ¿Creación de un visual? ¿A qué te refieres con eso?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-crear-macros-bd0f29dc-5b89-3616-c3bf-ddeeb04da2fb

Comment: @Yussef Necesito disparar el evento desde código c#

Comment: @Mateo En cuanto a no tener que crear un visual es bastante obvio, osea no tener que crear ninguna ventana con barras de progreso ni botones, la idea es utilizar el programa que ya exista instalada que cumpla la función de copia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que usar 2 funciones de `user32.dll`

- PostMessage: Enviará un mensaje a un proceso
- keybd_event: maneja eventos del teclado

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);


[STAThread]
static void Main()
{

    //abre una ventana del explorer en la ruta indicada
    var procceso = Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\prueba");
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //En mi caso esto no era necesario pero lo puse por las dudas

    //En el mejor de los casos se debería haber podido usar procceso.MainWindowHandle, pero no tengo idea porque no resulta
    //La solución fue buscar la lista de procesos activos, y determinar por el título de la ventana a cual correspondia
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");

    foreach (Process proc in processes)
    {
        if (proc.MainWindowTitle == "prueba") //prueba es el título de mi ventana
        {
            keybd_event(0xA2, 0x9d, 0, 0); //se mantiene la tecla control presionada
            PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, 0x0100, 86, 0); //se envía a la ventana la tecla V
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //puede que esto tampoco sea necesario
            keybd_event(0xA2, 0x9d, 0x0002, 0); //se suelta la tecla control
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: La documentación sugiere que uses `SendInput` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event

Comment: Gracias por ayudar, el código funciona pero me queda una duda, si es posible lograrlo sin abrir una nueva ventana o al menos cerrarla sin que el usuario note que fue abierta

Comment: Con proc.CloseMainWindow();  se cierra la ventana. Pero no estoy seguro de que si se puede hacer que el usuario no lo note. Tu básicamente lo que quieres es imitar los movimientos de un usuario, para eso la ventana tiene que estar abierta para `pegar`. Debes jugar con  "Thread.Sleep" colocando más de estos y cambiando los valores para lograr el efecto más cercano a lo que buscas. Por otro lado, te lo dije en una publicación anterior, es que es más fácil y a pruebas de fallas copiar los archivos por `File.Copy` y hacer la interfaz gráfica con un progressbar